# $(window).resize event not working 100% smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run the following code on a page (#home) that should smoothly inject a slider or if the page  container is under 480px leave the page as is.

I cannot get the resize event to work 100% smoothly.

If I reduce the window the script (js.slide.js) wont get triggered but the content will be loaded in (slide.php). If I continue to reduce the window a little extra it will all work ok.

Could anyone please advise as to how I could get this working smoothly. The code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($("#home").length > 0 ){ 

var homeSlideShow = {
    $promoArea: $('#promo-area'),
    $currentContent: $('#promo-area').contents(),
    $pageContainer: $('.page'),

    init: function(){
        var hSS = homeSlideShow;            
        if (hSS.$pageContainer.width() > 480 ){
            hSS.setTheSlideShow();
        } else{
            hSS.$promoArea.html(hSS.$currentContent);
        }

    },

    setTheSlideShow: function(){
        var hSS = homeSlideShow;                        
        $.getScript(myscript_wp_vars.temp_dir + '/js/slide.js', function(){
        hSS.$promoArea.load(myscript_wp_vars.temp_dir + '/libs/slide.php #c4u-slide',
        function(){
        var options = {
                    preloader: false,
                    nextButton: true,
                    prevButton: true,
                    animateStartingFrameIn: true,
                    transitionThreshold: 250                        
                };

                var sequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence"),
                    $slideShow = $("#c4u-slide");
                });

        });
    }   

};




//
//  Check page size
//
if (homeSlideShow.$pageContainer.width() > 480 ){
    homeSlideShow.setTheSlideShow();
}



//
//  On window resize
//
$(window).resize(function() {   
    homeSlideShow.init();   
});

}// END home.length

});//End $(document).ready(function()
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance or advice.

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.resize event is triggered multiple times, depending of browser's behaviour. I'll suggest you to try this:

```
var timeoutResize;
$(window).resize(function(){ 
        if(typeof timeoutResize != 'undefined') clearTimeout(timeoutResize);
        timeoutResize = setTimeout(function(){homeSlideShow.init();},50);

    });
```

Comment: There is a great jquery extension from Ben Alman for throttling and debouncing events: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: Cheers roasted I bumped up the timeout a little bit but it works great. @nxtwrld Thanks for the heads up on throttling and debouncing events, very usefull info specially with window resize. Cheers